# C# Unexpected EOF or 0 bytes on windows XP .NET 4.0

Tags: ssl

I am trying to send XML file over TLS protocol to the server that uses TLS 1.0 and 1.2 The program is working fine on windows 7 but for some strange reason I get error when running it on windows XP. I saw many people with the same problem but without a fix since I can't change the line to:

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

because the server is using using TLS 1.0 what should I do?

Comment: Change the `SecurityProtocol` to `SecurityProtocolType.Tls`?

Comment: I already have that.

Comment: Be aware that SChannel in Windows XP doesn't support TLS 1.2, so unless the server allows negotiation of TLS 1.0, it's not going to work unless you use another TLS client library

Comment: The served does support TLS 1.0 Tested it on windows 7 and it worked fine, but when I ran the program on windows xp I got the error above.